# Moving vector anchor points in After Effects

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I am trying to do a simple animation in After Effects. I have drawn a straight line with the pen tool, now I would like to animate the movement of one end of the line (while the other end remains in place). I know that I can add two puppet points to each end of the line to do this. But because the line is a vector line, I think that there must be some way to utilize this, the puppet tool does in some ways disort the line (making the edge more sharp when bending in some angles for instance).

Is there a good way of doing this?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but - add a keyframe on the path and move the point. That's it. No need for puppet points or anything like that.

Comment: I just realized that too. Im really new to this program!

Comment: I've been using After Effects for years and I still forget how to do basic things all the time!